# How to list mysql data horizontally

Tags: mysql

I have a table I am trying to get counts by hour of day for a distinct column

```
| Name  | HR  |  # | 
+---+---+-----+----+
| A     | 00  | 10 |
| A     | 01  | 11 |  
| B     | 00  | 8  |
| B     | 01  | 9  | 
| C     | 00  | 6  | 
| C     | 01  | 7  | 
+-----+---+--+--+---+


00  10  8  6
01  11  9  7
```

I need to group by HR but list counts from all letters per hour. I tried creating a procedure that would loop through it all but no luck.

Comment: It's called crosstab and mysql doesn't support it natively.  There are plenty of questions about it here on SO - search.

Comment: `Pivot` might be a better choice than crosstab - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pivot+mysql

Comment: This must be today's homework as this is 3rd such question today.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) will suffice?

```
SELECT HR, GROUP_CONCAT(`#`) FROM my_table GROUP BY HR
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8c64/1/0).

You can then split the (string) result on the delimiter, which is a comma by default but can be changed to any desired character (such as [U+001E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1e/), the ASCII "record separator") using the `SEPARATOR` keyword.